# How to get Firestore document string to display? Can't perform state update, async function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect, react-functional-component

I have an AuthProvider/context providing firebase authentication. In a lower component I'm trying to render current user data from Firestore, such as a username, when they log in.

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

    function login(email, password) {
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false);

            if (currentUser) {
                const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid);
                docRef.get().then(function(doc){
                    if(doc && doc.exists) {
                        setCurrentUsername(doc.data().username);
                        console.log(currentUsername)
                    }
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("no document:", error);
                });
            } else {
                // no user logged in
            };

        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [login])

const value = {
        currentUser, //firebase
        signup,
        login,
        logout,
        resetPassword,
        currentFullname,
        currentUsername,
        currentEmail,
        loading,
        setLoading,
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

```
async function handleLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            setError("")
            setLoading(true)
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
        } catch {
            setError("Incorrect email or password")
        }

        setLoading(false)
    }
```

Only on logging in do I want to fetch additional user information from Firestore since Firebase authentication only has uid and email. I get the "can't perform React state update on an unmounted component" error.

Firestore data is structured like: collection("users") --> document (firebase uid) --> username: someUsername, firstname: bobSmith, etc...

Comment: Is there error happening in this provider, or in some child component consuming *some* auth context?

Comment: oooo... it says in the console! I have a login modal popup with another async function for handling the login event.

Comment: Can you try to provide a more complete code example then? Where is `handleLogin` in relation to the state that it is trying to update? If this is state *in* a modal is the modal being closed before the authentication resolves?

Comment: OMG I just forgot to pass the useContext value props loading and setLoading! I got rid of the error! .... There's a warning now T_T which I guess is better. React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: ' currentUser', and 'currentUsername'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Ok, sounds like it is resolved or no longer reproducible. Voting to close. Cheers.

Comment: Hmm, I think `currentUser` should just be `user` since you set `currentUser` and it won't be updated yet in the rest of the callback function, and same with `currentUsername`. You likely don't want any dependencies either, you want this effect to run once upon mount, and unsubscribe when unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Code works for me now and has been updated to help any future people.

I had forgot to pass in a useContext value prop.

And then I changed the useEffect dependency array to login. Thanks Drew for guiding me through!